# How can a history of addresses that have owned an ENS name be read on a block explorer?

Tags: ens

ENS is nice, is it possibly to easily access a history of addresses that have owned an ENS name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etherscan allows you to view the [newOwner events](https://etherscan.io/ens?filter=newowners). You could likely pull data from there, or filter the events on your own node to build a block-by-block ownership log.